# How can I get the number of type parameters declared in a class?

Tags: java, reflection

I'd like to get the number of type prameters that a given class declares. For example, the class `java.util.List` declares one type parameter. `java.util.Map` declares two. And `java.util.function.BiFunction` declares three.

Ideally, I'd have a method that accepts a `Class` object and returns that count. Something like

```
SomeUtility.getCountOfTypeParameters(java.util.List.class);
```

**Note: I'm not interested in the type *arguments* provided when declaring, for example, a variable of type `List<String>`.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Class` class provides a [`getTypeParameters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getTypeParameters()) method that

> Returns an array of `TypeVariable` objects that represent the type
>   variables declared by the generic declaration represented by this
>   `GenericDeclaration` object, in declaration order. Returns an array of
>   length 0 if the underlying generic declaration declares no type
>   variables.

You can just check the length of the returned array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class<Map> clazz = Map.class;
    TypeVariable<Class<Map>>[] parameters = clazz.getTypeParameters();
    System.out.println(parameters.length);
}
```

prints

```
2
```